# store 50000 records per month

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I'm working on a HR system. i need to store information about 50000 employees every month. (Same employees will be repeated next month also with any changes to their data like job or compensation changes)
What is the best approach to store such data. 
Is it better to save in a single table or to save data to a new table for every month.

I need to show reports based on a period of time say from jan to may. in this case if i'm using separate tables for each month will it be feasible to run a query on this. Also is it possible to pass table name in variable.

Comment: One single table. 50000 rows is nothing.

Comment: increments of 50000 per month

Comment: Nothing per month is still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You can store in single table. Any Conventional DBMS can effectively handle such amount of data. They are designed to store and access millions of records at a time. So No worries.

Comment: In addition to @DheerajRoy what you have to worry about is data duplication https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization You can create additional tables to store name/position separately from month salary.